EF Core add update conditions based on table columns
EF Core's default is to use the primary key as the update condition.
I want to add the year when updating the year column in the table.
I need SQL statements like this to be generated by EF Core:
update person 
set name = 'tom' 
where id = 1 and year = 2024

Is there any way to do this?

Why?!? The primary key by definition is unique and identifies the row - adding a year to it doesn't give you any benefit.....

Search for EF Core ExecuteUpdate, it is creted for such purpose.

@marc_s, I assume update one record if it has Year = 2024, otherwise do nothing.

Because we need the year to locate the table.

Then surely your primary key would be (id, year) rather than id?

I'm not sure if I correctly understood your question.
You can try this if it helps
var person = context.Person
    .Where(p => p.Id == 1 && p.Year == 2024)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (person != null)
{
    // execute your update here
}


What is needed is that the final generated SQL statement has the year as a condition
